# Apply a function to all fields of an array of structs in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I need to apply a function (namely `mean`) to all fields of an array of structs. I.e., if I have the following array of structs:

```
A(1).x = 1;
A(1).y = 2;
A(2).x = 3;
A(2).y = 4;
```

I want to find the mean of the x values and the mean of the y values. The solution should work for any number of fields in the struct.

My initial thought was to use `structfun`, but now I'm stuck with the problem of converting an array of structs into a struct of arrays. I guess I can use a loop to iterate over the field names returned by `fieldnames` but maybe there's a more straightforward way.

Comment: If you would like to create struct of arrays and then use `structfun` for `mean` calculations, try out this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25631349/3293881)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution I know

```
F=fieldnames(A)
G=struct()
for ix=1:numel(F)
   G.(F{ix})=mean([A.(F{ix})]);
end
```

I came across another idea to solve this:

```
cell2struct(cellfun(@(x)(mean([A.(x)])),fieldnames(A),'uni',false),fieldnames(A),1)
```

If a vector and not a struct is the intended output, remove the outer `cell2struct`

Answer (score 3):

If the contents are scalars: convert from struct to cell, and then from cell to matrix:

```
mean(cell2mat(squeeze(struct2cell(A))), 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

If you are looking to create a struct of arrays and then perform `mean` with `structfun`, you can try this no-loop approach -

```
%// Get fieldnames
fns = fieldnames(A)

%// Get numeric values from the fields and store as numeric array
arrayvals = reshape(struct2array(A),numel(fns),[])

%// Convert to cell array so that struct of arrays could be obtained
data = mat2cell(arrayvals,ones(1,numel(fns)),size(arrayvals,2))

%// Convert to struct of arrays as you were looking to work with
A1 = cell2struct(data, fns, 1)

%// Finally the mean values with structfun
meanvals = structfun(@mean, A1)
```

Output (showing A and A1) -

```
A = 
1x2 struct array with fields:
    x
    y
A1 = 
    x: [1 3]
    y: [2 4]
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you would like to jump into the `mean` results without being bothered with `structfun`, you can directly convert your struct to a numeric array and get the mean values this way -

```
meanvals = mean(reshape(struct2array(A),numel(fieldnames(A)),[]),2)
```